# Curl Get with site some and save csv

Tags: csv, curl, preg-match-all

i get in site picture title description image path etc and wants to save in csv file can help for this.

i get the preg_match_all with curl and i can print in screen.

**How can i save and write .csv format**

```
    function get_web_page( $url )
    {
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
        );

        $ch      = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        $content = curl_exec( $ch );
        $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
        $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
        $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );

        $header['errno']   = $err;
        $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
        $header = $content;
        return $header;
    }
```

For loop categories page

```
    $products = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++) {                 // Page categories

        $url = "https://www.sitename.com/pages?tp=$i";
        $c = get_web_page($url);


        $mylinks = '@showcasePicture">(.*?)<a href="/(.*?)"@si';
        preg_match_all($mylinks, $c, $dgetlinks);  // Get Page link
        array_push($array_link, $dgetlinks);


    }
```

Get image title etc but cant get in csv format

```
    for ($i = 1; $i <2 ; $i++) {              // Count categories Page 
        for ($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++) {                   // Count Products Categories
            $dgetlinks = $array_link[$i][2][$j];
            $linked = "https://sitename.com/" . $dgetlinks;
            $d = get_web_page($linked);

            $price = '@<div class="row18">(.*?)</div>@si';
            $img_regex = '@lightbox-link="\/\/(.*?)"@si';
            $description_regex = '@<div class="ProductDetail">(.*?)</div>@si';
            $title_regex = '@<td colspan="3" class="col3"><h1>(.*?)</h1></td>@si';





            $products[] = [
                'title' => preg_match_all($title_regex, $d, $title),
                'description' => preg_match_all($description_regex, $d, $description),
                'picture' => preg_match_all($img_regex, $d, $img),  //Get Picture
                'price' => preg_match_all($price, $d, $price) // Get price
            ];



        }
    }
```

Create and save csv file

```
//Create CSV file
//$decoded_file = json_decode($products, true);
$fp = fopen(__DIR__.'/file2.csv', 'w');

fputcsv($fp, array_keys($products[0]));

//foreach ($decoded_file as $fields) { 
foreach ($products as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

i found this way